# read file in spark jobs from google cloud platform

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using spark on google cloud platform.
Apparently I'm reading a file from the filesystem `gs://<bucket>/dir/file`, but the log output prompts

> FileNotFoundException: `gs:/bucket/dir/file (No such file or dir exist)

The missing `/` is obviously the problem. How can I solve this?

[image: error message]

This is my code:

```
val files = Array(("call 1","gs://<bucket>/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/test/123.wav"))
val splitAudioFiles = sc.parallelize(files.map(x => splitAudio(x, 5, sc)))

def splitAudio(path: (String, String), interval: Int, sc: SparkContext): (String, Seq[(String,Int)]) = {
   val stopWords = sc.broadcast(loadTxtAsSet("gs://<bucket>/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/test/stopword.txt")).value
   val keyWords = sc.broadcast(loadTxtAsSet("gs://<bucket>/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/test/KeywordList.txt")).value

   val file = new File((path._2))
   val audioTitle = path._1
   val fileFormat: AudioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file)
   val format = fileFormat.getFormat
```

Comment: Please copy the content of the error message as text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're making use of AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(URL), which does not support gs:// URIs. Instead, you'll need to use the Hadoop FileSystem interface to acquire an InputStream for the file and make use of AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(InputStream). I *think* something like this should work:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

val sc: SparkContext = ...
val urls : RDD[URL] = ...
val formats : RDD[AudioFileFormat] = urls.map(url => {
    val asUri = url.toURI  
    val conf = new Configuration()
    val hadoopPath = new Path(asUri)
    val hadoopFs = hadooPath.getFileSystem(conf)
    val inputStream = hadoopFs.open(hadoopPath)
    AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(inputStream)
})
```

Comment: As an addendum, if you don't have easy access to `sc.hadoopConfiguration` (for example, if you're opening the files from inside worker tasks) then it's also fine to just do `hadoopPath.getFileSystem(new Configuration())`, since `Configuration` loads resources appropriately based on the various classpaths configured.

Comment: Good catch, Dennis. Updated the answer to use new Configuration()